# Does Sitecore 8 allow to customize the role manager table?

Tags: sitecore, customization, role

I have the list of roles in an external database which can be exposed as a RESTful service. Can Sitecore allow to write C# code so that the Role Manager can get and display the list of roles instead of hardcoding those roles?

If so, how to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore uses the standard .NET Membership model, so you can write your own custom membership provider and you should be able to pull in the roles from your service.

The steps usually involve the following (from [linked SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945187/sitecore-authenticate-users-against-external-membership-database)):

```
 1. Adding a connection string to connectionstrings.config 
 2. Adding membership/role provider definitions to the system.web section of web.config
 3. Activating switchers
 4. Creating a new domain for the users/roles from custom provider
 5. Adding domain/provider mappings
```

Some links:

- http://www.mintydog.com/2013/09/a-custom-membership-provider-in-sitecore-part-1/
- https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/sitecore6modules/ad/low-level_sitecore_cms_security_and_custom_providers.pdf
- [Sitecore Custom Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635480/sitecore-custom-membership-provider)
- [Sitecore authenticate users against external membership database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945187/sitecore-authenticate-users-against-external-membership-database)